# adding ajax load more to display images from meta box

Tags: ajax, metabox

I am using [metabox's](http://metabox.io) advance file uploader to upload images.

```
<?php  $images = rwmb_meta( 'tj_file_advanced', 'type=image&size=YOURSIZE');



    foreach ( $images as $image ) { ?>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="boxe">
                <?php echo "<img src='{$image['full_url']}'/>";     ?>
            </div>
        </div>

<?php } ?> 

<div class="loadmore" onclick="loadMore()"></div>
```

Currently, I have only uploaded 3 images, so it only shows 3 images. I want to upload more images. It should only show 3 images in the beginning and after i click the load more it should show another 3 images and show on.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done just following regular way to use Ajax in WordPress.

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

First register a script file and also create an AJAX Call.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'meta-ajaxscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-init.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
wp_localize_script( 'meta-ajaxscript', 'ajaxMeta', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
));
```

Second, Wrap your metadata with a parent element by class or ID

```
<div id="metaWrapper">

    <?php  
    $images = rwmb_meta( 'tj_file_advanced', 'type=image&size=YOURSIZE'); 
    $ppp = 3;
    foreach (array_slice($images, 0, $ppp) as $image) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="boxe">
            <?php echo "<img src='{$image['full_url']}'/>"; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

</div>

<div class="loadmore"></div>
```

Third write down some ajax call script into ajax-init.js.

```
$( ".loadmore" ).on( "click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $container = $('#metaWrapper'),
      ppp = 3,
      number = $container.find( '> .col-md-4').length,
      page = number / ppp;

  $.ajax({
    url: ajaxMeta.ajaxurl,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      'page': page,
      'ppp': ppp,
       action: 'meta_fetch'
    },
    success: function( response ) {
      if(response == "")
          {
            // no content was found
            $('.loadmore').hide();
          }
          else
          {
            console.log(response);
            $container.append( response );
          }
      }
  });

  return false;
});
```

Now set up a PHP function to handle the AJAX request.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_meta_fetch', 'wpex_metadata_fetch' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_meta_fetch', 'wpex_metadata_fetch' );

function wpex_metadata_fetch() {

  $images = rwmb_meta( 'tj_file_advanced', 'type=image&size=YOURSIZE');

  $page = (int) $_POST['page'];
  $ppp  = (int) $_POST['ppp'];

  foreach (array_slice($images, $page*$ppp, $ppp) as $image) { ?>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="boxe">
          <?php echo "<img src='{$image['full_url']}'/>"; ?>
      </div>
  </div>
  <?php
  } 

  die();

}
```

hope it makes sense and happy Codding!

Answer (score 0):

ok. so your `loadMore()` should do something like these:

```
function loadMore() {
    var showing = $('#id').find( '> .col-md-4').length;
    $.ajax(
        // making ajax call to get more images passing variable showing
        success: function( data ) {
        $('#id').append( data );
        }
    );
}
```

and your php (ajax) script should return something like:

```
$images = rwmb_meta( 'tj_file_advanced', 'type=image&size=YOURSIZE');
$count = count( $images );
$offset = (int) $_POST['showing'];
for( $i = $offset; $i <= $count; $i++ ) {
    echo '<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="boxe">
                <img src="' . $images[$i]['full_url']. '" />
            </div>
        </div>';
}
die();
```

Note that you should wrap all your `col-md-4` in `#id`